# Problems setting up gsl with cmake

Tags: c++, installation, cmake, gnu, gsl

I was able to successfully configure and generate the build folder (KinectSLAM6D/build.). However, when I try to build it using make, I got an error  saying gsl is not found. I am pretty sure this is just a configuration issue as I have gsl installed (they're in usr/local), but I am unable to configure it. I have tried adding the following lines to CMakeList:

```
include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GSLCBLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${GSL_LIBRARIES} ${GSLCBLAS_LIBRARIES})
```

I have copied the pertinent output below. I have found a couple of answers to compiling with gsl (adding -lgsl). However, I have no clue where to put that in CMakeLists or the generated MakeList and MakeList2 files.

```
  Here's the generated output.
....
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Kinect6DSLAM.dir/src/GraphOptimizer_G2O.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Kinect6DSLAM.dir/src/CKinect2DRawlog.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable Kinect6DSLAM
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libmrpt-base.so, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.2.4
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libmrpt-base.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_highgui.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libmrpt-base.so, may conflict with libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
    ../gicp/libgicp.a(gicp.o): In function `dgc::gicp::GICPPointSet::ComputeMatrices()':
    gicp.cpp:(.text+0x462): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_alloc'
    gicp.cpp:(.text+0x470): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_alloc'
... a bunch more undefined references to gsl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Kinect6DSLAM] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Kinect6DSLAM.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This if the full CMakeList.txt. I am trying to run Miguel Algaba's SLAM project.

```
PROJECT(KinectSLAM6D)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
      cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)  # Required by CMake 2.7+
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

# Set the output directory for the build executables
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

#Add here your project dependencies
FIND_PACKAGE(MRPT REQUIRED hwdrivers maps graphslam) #Add here your project dependencies
FIND_PACKAGE(PCL REQUIRED) 
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

# Required by StanfordGICP
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake) 
FIND_PACKAGE(GSL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GSLCBLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${GSL_LIBRARIES} ${GSLCBLAS_LIBRARIES})
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS system program_options REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp/ann_1.1.1/include/ANN)
# G2O library

# Set up the top-level include directories
SET( G2O_INCLUDE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/EXTERNAL/g2o CACHE PATH "Directory of G2O")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${G2O_INCLUDE})

# Add g2o lib dir
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${LINK_DIRECTORIES} "${G2O_INCLUDE}/lib" )

#Generate config.h 
configure_file(g2o/trunk/config.h.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/g2o/config.h)
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
INSTALL(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/g2o/config.h DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/g2o)

# Include the subdirectories
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(g2o/trunk)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR}) #You can use CPARSE or CHOLMOD
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CHOLMOD_INCLUDE_DIR}) 

set(G2O_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/g2o/trunk)
include_directories(${G2O_DIR})
link_directories(${G2O_DIR}/lib)


# Declare the target (an executable)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(Kinect6DSLAM kinect6DSLAM.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber.h
./include/KinectGrabber_OpenNI.h
./src/KinectGrabber_OpenNI.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber_Rawlog.h
./src/KinectGrabber_Rawlog.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber_Rawlog2.h
./src/KinectGrabber_Rawlog2.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber_MRPT.h
./src/KinectGrabber_MRPT.cpp
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_SURF_GPU.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_Generic.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_ORB.h
./include/VisualFeatureMatcher.h
./include/VisualFeatureMatcher_Generic.h
./include/PointCloudViewer.h
./include/PointCloudViewer_MRPT.h
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_SURF_GPU.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_Generic.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_ORB.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureMatcher_Generic.cpp
./src/PointCloudViewer_MRPT.cpp
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator.h
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_SVD.h
./src/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_SVD.cpp
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_RANSAC.h
./src/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_RANSAC.cpp
./include/ICPPoseRefiner.h
./include/ICPPoseRefiner_PCL.h
./src/ICPPoseRefiner_PCL.cpp
./include/ICPPoseRefiner_StanfordGICP.h
./src/ICPPoseRefiner_StanfordGICP.cpp
./include/Miscellaneous.h
./src/Miscellaneous.cpp
./include/FrameRGBD.h
./src/FrameRGBD.cpp
./include/PointCloudDownsampler.h
./src/PointCloudDownsampler.cpp
./include/KeyframeLoopDetector.h
./src/KeyframeLoopDetector.cpp
./include/GraphOptimizer.h
./include/GraphOptimizer_MRPT.h
./src/GraphOptimizer_MRPT.cpp
./include/GraphOptimizer_G2O.h
./src/GraphOptimizer_G2O.cpp
./include/CKinect2DRawlog.h
./src/CKinect2DRawlog.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Kinect6DSLAM ${MRPT_LIBS}
                   ${PCL_LIBRARIES} 
                   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                       ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                   #GICP
                                   ${GSL_LIBRARIES} 
                                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp/ann_1.1.1/lib/libANN.a
                                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp/libgicp.a
                   #G2O
                   core  math_groups types_slam3d
                           solver_csparse #You can use CPARSE or CHOLMOD
                           solver_cholmod ${CHOLMOD_LIBRARIES}
                   )

# Declare the target (an executable)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(PairwiseAlignmentSteps PairwiseAlignmentSteps.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber.h
./include/KinectGrabber_OpenNI.h
./src/KinectGrabber_OpenNI.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber_Rawlog.h
./src/KinectGrabber_Rawlog.cpp
./include/KinectGrabber_MRPT.h
./src/KinectGrabber_MRPT.cpp
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_SURF_GPU.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_Generic.h
./include/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_ORB.h
./include/VisualFeatureMatcher.h
./include/VisualFeatureMatcher_Generic.h
./include/PointCloudViewer.h
./include/PointCloudViewer_MRPT.h
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_SURF_GPU.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_Generic.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureDescriptorExtractor_ORB.cpp
./src/VisualFeatureMatcher_Generic.cpp
./src/PointCloudViewer_MRPT.cpp
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator.h
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_SVD.h
./src/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_SVD.cpp
./include/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_RANSAC.h
./src/Visual3DRigidTransformationEstimator_RANSAC.cpp
./include/ICPPoseRefiner.h
./include/ICPPoseRefiner_PCL.h
./src/ICPPoseRefiner_PCL.cpp
./include/ICPPoseRefiner_StanfordGICP.h
./src/ICPPoseRefiner_StanfordGICP.cpp
./include/Miscellaneous.h
./src/Miscellaneous.cpp
./include/FrameRGBD.h
./src/FrameRGBD.cpp
./include/PointCloudDownsampler.h
./src/PointCloudDownsampler.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PairwiseAlignmentSteps ${MRPT_LIBS}
                   ${PCL_LIBRARIES} 
                   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                       ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                   #GICP
                                   ${GSL_LIBRARIES} 
                                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp/ann_1.1.1/lib/libANN.a
                                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gicp/libgicp.a
                   )

# Set optimized building:
IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -mtune=native")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
target_link_libraries(Kinect6DSLAM ${LIBS})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something tells me, that adding `target_link_libraries(Kinect6DSLAM ${LIBS})` will help you.

Also, instead of constructs like

```
set(VAR ${VAR} somethingelse)
```

you can use this:

```
list(APPEND VAR somethingelse)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Adding that line at the end didn't work. I'm starting to think it  might not be a problem with CMake,  but I have no idea what could be the cause.

Comment: Are you sure that `${LIBS}` var contains "-lgsl"? Add `message(STATUS ${LIBS})` to find out.

Comment: It has it: -- -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

Comment: I see you are linking static libs. Some linker are sensitive to order in which static libs are passed in. IIRC, libs without dependencies should go last. Try to play with static libs order in `target_link_libraries()` invocation.

Comment: Moving gsl library in target_link_libraries to the end solves the problem! I am getting another error that's memory related, so it should work if I try a different laptop. Thanks a lot!